# How to align columns with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I am currently learning Flexbox Layout and I can not find a solution to my problem.

I tried with justify-content and flex-basis but it does not work. Does anyone have the solution ?

The result I would like : [image: here]

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;

}

#first {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-shrink: 2;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="column" id="first">First</div>
  <div class="column" id="second">Second</div>
  <div class="column">Third</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="column">First</div>
  <div class="column">Second</div>
  <div class="column">Third</div>
  <div class="column">Fourth</div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qdsbacvn/

Comment: What is your expected layout? your first element in the top row is smaller than the two below it because of their margins.

Comment: I add a photo of the result that I want to get on my post. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You don't need margin: 0 auto and justify-content: space-between, width: 100% is by default, can be done with only one parent element (section) etc.

Comment: Oh you right ! Thanks for the reminder ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for CSS grid where you don't need a lot of complex code:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  margin: 2% auto;
  grid-gap:2%;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr);
}

.column {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  padding: 5px;
}

#first {
  grid-column:span 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="column" id="first">First</div>
  <div class="column" id="second">Second</div>
  <div class="column">Third</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="column">First</div>
  <div class="column">Second</div>
  <div class="column">Third</div>
  <div class="column">Fourth</div>
</section>
```

With flexbox you can try the following:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

#first {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis:4%; /*2 x (padding + margin)*/
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="column" id="first">First</div>
  <div class="column" id="second">Second</div>
  <div class="column">Third</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="column">First</div>
  <div class="column">Second</div>
  <div class="column">Third</div>
  <div class="column">Fourth</div>
</section>
```

Since your are using `flex-basis:0` only padding/margin are considered before calculating the free space. The trick is to make sure we have the same free space in both situation thus we add to `flex-basis` of the big element the margin/padding that aren't present in the first case.

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot, it's not a Flexbox Layout but I keep this somewhere in my head. I will learn CSS Grid verry soon ;-)

Comment: @maher added a flexbox solution ;)

Comment: I am starting to understand the logic behind the margin problem thanks to your code. I really appreciate thank you

Comment: @maher not only margin, but also padding, added more details

Comment: Very clean solutions. Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

Check my code. I have increased slightly the flex box value.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

#first {
  flex-grow: 2.2;
  flex-shrink: 2;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="column" id="first">First</div>
  <div class="column">Second</div>
  <div class="column">Third</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="column">First</div>
  <div class="column">Second</div>
  <div class="column">Third</div>
  <div class="column">Fourth</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you it's perfect but can you explain me how and why the 2.2 value on flex-grow properties fixed my problem ?

Comment: The issue is with the margin and padding, if you set it to zero it's is aligned correctly.

Comment: You right, I tried without us. It confirms the explanation above. Thank you !

Comment: @maher there are more experienced programmers than me, that can give you better answers.

Comment: All your answer are great if it might helps others ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A bit overkill for your use case but a much more robust solution in case you need to add more rows or your margins need to change size.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.column {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column
}
.column:first-child {
  flex:2;
}
.col-row {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.col-row > div{
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  margin:1vw;
  padding:1vw;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="col-row">
       <div>First</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-row">
      <div>First</div>
      <div>Second</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
     <div class="col-row">
        <div>Second</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-row">
        <div>Third</div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="col-row">
        <div>Third</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-row">
        <div>Fourth</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's very interesting, the html it's more precise/structured that mine and the result is perfect. I will try to reproduce that. Thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: Overcomplicating, flex-direction: row is by default.

Comment: @VXp Since the OP is clearly not super familiar with flexbox the one extra line to be explicit seems worth it

Comment: Just unneeded line of css which for some can turn into a habit, so caution, fragile, handle with care or better not handle at all, leave it alone, in the corner where it belongs. Since the OP isn't using it, I'm pretty sure of his awareness.

Comment: That's right I'm aware of that, nevertheless it's nice to understand the code (maybe you should put it in comment ? for beginners' understanding).