# Flex box do not line up with each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have two rows of flexbox. The first row has 3 items, each takes up 4 columns. The second row has 2 items, one takes up 4 columns and the other takes up 8 columns. But when the two rows are stacked together, the sizes of each row do not match with each other. i.e. the first item on each row have different sizes.

Here is a picture of what I meant:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWcTr.jpg

```css
.flex-display {
    display: flex;
}
.pretty-container {
    background-color: rgb(38, 47, 53);
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:rgb(54, 69, 79);
}
.four.columns { width: calc(100% / 3); }
.eight.columns { width: calc(100% / 3 * 2); }

body {
    font-size: 1.5em; /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #EBEBEB; }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row flex-display" style="justify-content: space-between;">
            <div id="test4-container" class="pretty-container four columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 1</div>
                    <div id="test4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test5-container" class="pretty-container eight columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 2</div>
                    <div id="test5"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row flex-display" style="justify-content: space-between;">
            <div id="test1-container" class="pretty-container four columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 3</div>
                    <div id="test1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test2-container" class="pretty-container four columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 4</div>
                    <div id="test2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test3-container" class="pretty-container four columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 5</div>
                    <div id="test3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/55543039/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use CSS Grid for your solution. I have explained the `grid-area` in the comments. Otherwise the other styles are yours.

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #EBEBEB;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* 3 Columns */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; /* 2 Columns */
  grid-column-gap: 15px; /* Margin between columns */
  grid-row-gap: 15px; /* Margin between rows */
  background: #36454F;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container > div {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: rgb(38, 47, 53);
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

.top-tracks1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; /* Start at 1, End at 2 */
}

.top-artists1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 4; /* Row start at 1 and end at 2, Column start at 2 and end at 4 */
}

.top-tracks2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; /* Row Start at 2 and end at 3, Column start at 1 and end at 2 */
}

.top-artists2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; /* Row Start at 2 and end at 3, Column start at 2 and end at 3 */
}

.summary {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4; /* Row Start at 2 and end at 3, Column start at 3 and end at 4 */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-tracks1"> Top Tracks </div>
  <div class="top-tracks2"> Top Tracks </div>
  <div class="top-artists1"> Top Artists </div>
  <div class="top-artists2"> Top Artists </div>
  <div class="summary"> Summary </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware that grid [is not supported properly for IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) or earlier...  which unfortunately still has [3% market share](https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) as of July 2019...

Answer (score 1):

you add margin in between, so when there's only two, there  is 10px less of space used by margins. you need to add this extra missing to the bigger boxes.

`flex-shrink`, `flex-grow` won't be of any help here, `flex-basis` will require also to take into calculation those 10px, flex do not come with a gutter system ;).

```css
.flex-display {
    display: flex;
}
.pretty-container {
    background-color: rgb(38, 47, 53);
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing:border-box/* will include padding and border into calculation*/
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
   
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:rgb(54, 69, 79);
}
.four.columns { width: calc(100% / 3); }
.eight.columns { width: calc(100% / 3 * 2 + 10px) ;/* add those 10px margins missing and unseen by flex when this is meant not to take room from 2 boxes */}

body {
    font-size: 1.5em; /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #EBEBEB; }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row flex-display" style="justify-content: space-between;">
            <div id="test4-container" class="pretty-container four columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 1</div>
                    <div id="test4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test5-container" class="pretty-container eight columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 2</div>
                    <div id="test5"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row flex-display" style="justify-content: space-between;">
            <div id="test1-container" class="pretty-container four columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 3</div>
                    <div id="test1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test2-container" class="pretty-container four columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 4</div>
                    <div id="test2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="test3-container" class="pretty-container four columns">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-banner">Item 5</div>
                    <div id="test3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```